# self.send(method, =, value) does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a Ruby class where the `initialize` method takes a hash of options. I then have those options as `attr_accessor`s for the class. Now, I could do something like

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone

  def initialize(options)
    self.name = options[:name]
    self.email = options[:email]
    self.phone = options[:phone]
  end
end

User.new(:name => 'Some Name', :email => 'some-name@some-company.com', :phone => 435543093)
```

but it doesn't feel very DRY to me. Instead, I would like to do

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone

  def initialize(options)
    options.each do |option_name, option_value|
      # Does not work!!
      self.send(option_name, '=', option_value)

      # Does not work either!!
      self.send(option_name, '=' + option_value)
    end
  end
end

User.new(:name => 'Some Name', :email => 'some-name@some-company.com', :phone => 435543093)
```

but I cannot get the syntax to work!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You're getting this problem because the method name is wrong. When using a send with a setter, you'll need to include the `=` in the method name, like this:

```
self.send("#{option_name}=", option_value)
```

The above should do the trick.